# What's the best & safest encryption for passwords & emails?

Tags: email, encryption, hash

I'm going to encrypt & hash (I guess that's the same thing) my emails in my database.

Which hash or encryption is the best & safest and most hard to get information out from?

My site is basically a private streaming site which will get probably very much attacks and such and I guess if not a hacker will get into the database the police will later on. So, what should I use to protect my users to the maximum?

Kindly Regards.

Comment: Encrypting and Hashing aren't the same things. If you're interested in the "best", I would recommend you read up on security and make an informed decision based on your requirements, rather than just asking here.

Comment: If they are not the same thing, well OK. I'm not going to read up on security and such, I tought you guys knew. Anyone else here then?

Comment: @localGuy Well, if it is not worth your time "not going to read up on security" perhaps it is not worth the time for an answer.

Comment: @localGuy *I'm not going to read up on security and such*  In my humble opinion, perhaps you are the fool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, as Allan S. said, hashing and encryption aren't the same thing.

A hash function is mainly used to verify the integrity of a file because little differences in the file cause very different hashes. [Hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function)
Encryption, in a few words, is used to protect files or data from being stolen or watched by someone. [Cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptography)

Back to your question:
[Here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/20922/best-hash-algorithm) you could find some advice linked to some hashing function,there's a little explanation.

About encryption algorithms maybe you'll find something useful [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/24111/how-to-choose-an-algorithm) and [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3922/what-algorithm-could-should-be-used-to-encrypt-files-for-storage-on-untrusted-se/3950#3950).
Specifically related to databases I found [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/8036/what-is-the-best-way-to-store-sensitive-information-on-the-client).

Keep in mind that a every time valid solution doesn't exist, you need to find the one which fits better to your requirements.